# How to use HTML TestSuite as well as Test Cases on Selenium RC using IE

Tags: html, windows, internet-explorer, selenium-rc, test-suite

I am using Selenium RC in Internet Explorer. I have written some test cases in HTML. How can I write Test Suite in HTML including my test cases in HTML? I want to run the HTML Test Suite using Selenium RC in IE and Windows XP / Windows 7. How can I do this?

Comment: Selenium RC is officially deprecated. Don't use it for new work.

Comment: Yes, I am not using Selenium RC. I am using WebDriver now. @Quentin: Is it OK?

Comment: Selenium RC project is developed by ThoughtWorks and Openqa and its document updated http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.jsp in this link. Now Last update 13.01.2014 so project support is going on. We can use it for our future projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Selenium IDE version 1.8, Right click in "Test Case" section and Add all HTML test cases by selecting "Add Test Case" option.
Then Just Save this Test suite in HTML format by selecting "File > Save Test Suite" option.
After this Just create one .bat file with following content to execute this HTML Test Suite.

java -jar selenium-server.jar -port 4444 -htmlSuite "*chrome" "http://www.google.com/" "C:\Selenium\TestSuite.html" "C:\Selenium\TestSuiteResult.html"
pause

[image: Selenium IDE > Add Test Case]

Answer (score 1):

To create HTML Test Suite:

1. Open Selenium IDE
2. Record and create 2 TCs (In my case i) google1.html and ii) google2.html)
3. File --> Save Test Suite As --> Save the file as "GoogleTestSuite.html")

To execute Test Suite:

1. Open command line/terminal --> Go to the location where selenium-server (.jar) is located --> Run the following command:

   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0rc2.jar -port 4444 -htmlSuite "*iexplore" "http://www.google.com/" "C:\Selenium\GoogleTestSuite.html" "C:\Selenium\TestSuiteResult.html"

Note: TestSuiteResult.html will be created after running which contains the test result